# C# string interpolation-escaping double quotes and curly braces

Tags: c#, string-interpolation

guys,

I'm building a JSON object from an interpolated string, and not getting how escaping works. I have to use double quotes for the API.

This does not interpolate the expressions between the curly braces:

```
@"{{
                        ""name"":""{taskName}"", 
                        ""products"": [    
                                    {""product"": ""ndvi_image"", ""actions"": [""mapbox"", ""processed""]}, 
                                    {""product"": ""true_color"", ""actions"": [""mapbox"", ""processed""]}
                                  ], 
                        ""recurring"":true,
                        ""query"":    {
                                        ""date_from"": ""{dateFromString}"",
                                        ""date_to"": ""{dateToString}"",
                                        ""aoi"": {polygon}
                                    },
                        ""aoi_coverage_percentage"":90
                        }}";
```

This throws a bunch of errors-apparently, the curly brackets are not being escaped properly:

```
$"{{
                        ""name"":""{taskName}"", 
                        ""products"": [    
                                    {""product"": ""ndvi_image"", ""actions"": [""mapbox"", ""processed""]}, 
                                    {""product"": ""true_color"", ""actions"": [""mapbox"", ""processed""]}
                                  ], 
                        ""recurring"":true,
                        ""query"":    {
                                        ""date_from"": ""{dateFromString}"",
                                        ""date_to"": ""{dateToString}"",
                                        ""aoi"": {polygon}
                                    },
                        ""aoi_coverage_percentage"":90
                        }}";
```

How should I format it in order to preserve the internal double quotes and outer brackets while allowing for the values inside the single brackets to be interpolated?

Comment: perhaps it would be better to create an anonymous type and use a standard json serializer instead.  json is ubiquitous. there is no need to build it yourself considering that you might even end up serializing it incorrectly, for example, if the values can contain double quotes

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It seems that you have missed escape for the `products` and `query` objects:

```
$@"{{
    ""name"":""{taskName}"",
    ""products"": [
        {{""product"": ""ndvi_image"", ""actions"": [""mapbox"", ""processed""]}},
        {{""product"": ""true_color"", ""actions"": [""mapbox"", ""processed""]}}
    ],
    ""recurring"":true,
    ""query"": {{
        ""date_from"": ""{dateFromString}"",
        ""date_to"": ""{dateToString}"",
        ""aoi"": {polygon}
    }},
    ""aoi_coverage_percentage"":90
}}";
```

Comment: although technically correct, this approach is not easily maintainable and is error-prone as json could be malformed if one of the variables contains a double quote

Comment: Check out the new raw string literal for a much simpler syntax for this.

Answer (score 33):

Just in case someone else is considering doing the same, it would be better to create an anonymous type and serialize it to json for two reasons:

1. it's a lot more readable and maintainable (how long would it take someone to change the code because the json structure has changed while keeping all escapes in order -- especially if there are no unit tests?)
2. it's a lot more reliable (what if `taskName` has a double quote?)

Below uses json.net for serialization.

```
var jsonObj = new {
  name = taskName,
  products = new[] {
    new { product = "ndvi_image", actions = new [] { new { mapbox = "processed" } },
    new { product = "true_color", actions = new [] { new { mapbox = "processed" } }
  },
  recurring = true,
  query = new {
    date_from = dateFromString,
    date_to = dateToString,
    aoi = polygon
  },
  aoi_coverage_percentage = 90
};

var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj);
```

Comment: This is a much better answer

Comment: This should be the accepted answer IMHO... Even in the example, It's not clear what `polygon` is, and if it's really safe or already serialized.  And what if that changes, everything blows up on the other side.

Answer (score 26):

In addition to `@"..."` and `$"..."` C# supports `$@"..."` strings, which is what you are looking for when you build multi-line string literals that need to be interpolated:

```
$@"{{
    ""name"":""{taskName}"", 
    ""products"": [    
                {{""product"": ""ndvi_image"", ""actions"": [""mapbox"", ""processed""]}}, 
                {{""product"": ""true_color"", ""actions"": [""mapbox"", ""processed""]}}
              ], 
    ""recurring"":true,
    ""query"":   {{
                    ""date_from"": ""{dateFromString}"",
                    ""date_to"": ""{dateToString}"",
                    ""aoi"": {polygon}
                }},
    ""aoi_coverage_percentage"":90
}}";
```